# How to get min_tag_id and max_tag_id from instagram api in sandbox mode

Tags: php, instagram-api

Am working with an API development where i need to get `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` to get list of recently tagged posts from an application using php.

Comment: Please take the time to re-write your question. Think of those who are taking the time to read it. It is hard to provide help when there is no clear understanding on what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you in sandbox mode? thats probably why you are seeing no data, u dont need `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id`

In sandbox mode you will only see results of hashtag you (and your sandbox users) have posted

Comment: u will get no data in sandbox mode, it is expected, if u want to see data, choose a hashtag u have posted